# Multithreading # with functions with input parameters

Tags: c#, multithreading

I use multithreading this way with no problem

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(fun1));
            t1.Start();
            var t2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(fun2));
            t2.Start();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        public static void fun1()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < 51; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"i is {i}");
            }
        }
        public static void fun2()
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < 51; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"j is {j}");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

like it is clear the function has no input argument.but when I want use a function with even one parameter I face an ERROR.

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(fun1("str1")));
            t1.Start();
            var t2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(fun2("str2")));
            t2.Start();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        public static void fun1(string x)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < 51; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"i is {i}");
            }
        }
        public static void fun2(string y)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < 51; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"j is {j}");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

So please tell me how I can use a function with arguments(as input)in multithreading?

Comment: Try `new ThreadStart(() => fun2("str2"))`

Comment: Also, you should definitely consider using tasks instead of threads.

Comment: I agree with Lasse. Usually there is no need to go so low-level like threads with all their delicate intricacies w.r.t. setup, performance and synchronization, when lots of the work is already done by tasks as they are also much better integrated within the language.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please supply us with the error you're receiving?

Comment: You are seeing an error cause ThreadStart is a delegate. You can't pass arguments to delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following:

```
    string str = "string";
        var t1 = new Thread(
         o => 
        {
            fun1((string)o);    
        });
        t1.Start(str);
```

and same for fun2.

Comment: Theodor, there is something wrong in your proposition

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [this MSDN link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart?view=netframework-4.7.2) for more information on `ParameterizedThreadStart Delegate` to see how to pass parameters to methods using threading:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

public class Work
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Start a thread that calls a parameterized static method.
        Thread newThread = new Thread(Work.DoWork);
        newThread.Start(42);

        // Start a thread that calls a parameterized instance method.
        Work w = new Work();
        newThread = new Thread(w.DoMoreWork);
        newThread.Start("The answer.");
    }

    public static void DoWork(object data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Static thread procedure. Data='{0}'",
            data);
    }

    public void DoMoreWork(object data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Instance thread procedure. Data='{0}'",
            data);
    }
}
// This example displays output like the following:
//       Static thread procedure. Data='42'
//       Instance thread procedure. Data='The answer.'
```

For passing `multiple parameters`, you can create a class with properties and pass an object of this class filled with property values and access that class object in your threaded method as below:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

public class Work
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Start a thread that calls a parameterized static method.
        Thread newThread = new Thread(Work.DoWork);
        //create a class to hold multiple params
        DataClass objData = new DataClass();
        objData.Param1 = "value 1";
        objData.Param2 = "value 2";

        newThread.Start(objData);

        // Start a thread that calls a parameterized instance method.
        Work w = new Work();
        newThread = new Thread(w.DoMoreWork);
        newThread.Start(objData);
    }

    public static void DoWork(object data)
    {
        DataClass myData = (DataClass)data;
        Console.WriteLine("Static thread procedure. Data Param1='{0}'",
            data.Param1);
    }

    public void DoMoreWork(object data)
    {
        DataClass myData = (DataClass)data;
        Console.WriteLine("Instance thread procedure. Data Param2='{0}'",
            data.Param2);
    }
}
```